# ListObject Table Row Count

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel table with one header row and one data body row. I want to count the data body rows. When I'm trying to check how many rows my table has with

```
Set myWorkSheet= ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set myTable= myWorkSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
countrows = myTable.ListRows.Count
```

`countrows` contains `0`. If the has 2 or more rows, it gives the right row number. Why does it say 0 for one row ans is it the best way to count the rows or are there better ones?

**EDIT:**

Found out whats causing the problem. I use this lines to clear the table before i fill it again:

```
If tblChart.ListRows.Count >= 1 Then
    myTable.DataBodyRange.Delete
End If
```

After that operation the table looks like I described it. Without it and modifying the table to look like I described the table it worked. But why is it causing this problem?

Answer (score 2):

The ListObject property you are looking for is the `.DataBodyRange`.

```
    Dim myWorkSheet As Worksheet, myTable As ListObject, countRows As Long
    Set myWorkSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set myTable = myWorkSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
    countRows = myTable.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
    Debug.Print countRows
```

A comprehensive list of the ListObject properties is available at: [ListObject Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.listobject.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Responding late in-case Google search brings user here:
I found this problem as well. DataBodyRange object does not exist unless there are two rows of data. Not just two empty rows, but two rows of data in at least one column.
What I have found to work reliably is to test if DataBodyRange exists:

```js
If Not TableListObject.DataBodyRange is Nothing Then
  Debug.Print "Data Rows Count=", TableListObject.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
 Else
  Debug.Print "No Data in Table detected"
End if
```